# {{#if}} inside a {{#each}} with a parameter coming from the each item

Tags: meteor, spacebars

I have a {{#each}} that's essentially iterating through the users collections. I now wish to check if the user is an admin to set a switch (materialize). A simplified version:

```
{{#each getUsers}}
    testing: {{_id}}  {{#if isAdmin "tTEScMyjCedano2oT"}}checked="checked"{{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Here I am hard coding in the _id parameter in the `{{#if}}` and it works as expected. The `isAdmin` function works correctly, the `{{#if}}` works and the {{_id}} works as well (prints out the correct id).

But of course I do not want to hard code the id passed to `isAdmin` but want it to be `{{_id}}` however it doesn't work. i.e.

```
{{#each getUsers}}
    testing: {{_id}}  {{#if isAdmin "{{_id}}"}}checked="checked"{{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

does not work and neither does

```
{{#each getUsers}}
    testing: {{_id}}  {{#if isAdmin "{{../_id}}"}}checked="checked"{{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

nor

```
{{#each getUsers}}
    testing: {{_id}}  {{#if isAdmin {{id}}}}checked="checked"{{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use double quotes nor curly braces :

```
{{#each getUsers}}
  testing: {{_id}}  {{#if isAdmin _id}}checked="checked"{{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Will accept when I can. Is this because it is already in `{{}}` i.e. the ones from the `#if`?

Comment: Yes, at the moment you can't nest Spacebars subexpressions in a helper.

Comment: The reason this works is because in your `#each` statement, it changes the data context to refer to "each" user, therefore, instead of doing `user._id`, you can simply use `id` by itself because it already knows you are referring to the `user`